# Unable to load private key to request a certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, key, keystore, private-key

I have a private key with passphrase and when I try to do anything using OpenSSL, like `openssl req -key myprivatekey.key -new -out mydemande.csr`, I have this error :

```
unable to load Private Key
22100:error:0607607D:digital envelope routines:PKCS5_v2_PBE_keyivgen:unsupported prf:./crypto/evp/p5_crpt2.c:230:    
22100:error:06074078:digital envelope routines:EVP_PBE_CipherInit:keygen failure:./crypto/evp/evp_pbe.c:101:    
22100:error:23077073:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 algor cipherinit error:./crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:83:    
22100:error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:./crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:123:    
22100:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:./crypto/pem/pem_pkey.c:125:
```

hHelp!!

Answer (score 4):

The problème was the version of openSSl.
When i change the version of my openssl it works fine !!!

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Which version of Openssl would you recommend?

Comment: Just in case for someone, now it would be 3.0.3. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-exporting the PFX without extended properties